# Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler does not work

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I set thread's uncaughtExceptionHandler as shown in the code below but it does not work when a HibernateException is raised in the thread running. My jvm is 1.6.0_26. Any clue?

```
this.executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(new ThreadFactory() 
{
  public Thread newThread(Runnable r)   
  {
    Thread result = Executors.defaultThreadFactory().newThread(r);
    result.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() 
    {
       public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
      logger.error("error occurs while supervior is running", e);
    }
    })
    return result;
  }
});
```

Comment: the exception may not be happening in the thread?

Comment: I am not seeing where you actually started the thread.  Don't you need to run the thread for this code block to work?  Such as:  result.start() ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing where you actually started the thread.  Don't you need to run the thread for this code block to work?  Such as:

```
// execute Threads run method
result.start();
```

Comment: No, he is using an `Executor`, which will ask the supplied `ThreadFactory` to create threads, and then the executor will start them.

Comment: Ok.  The question has limited information and so it is hard to guess as to what the problem is.  I was just taking a stab at it. Do you have a guess?